# Powershell Exchange CU11 Pipe |

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have 4 Exchange 2013 servers on 2012R2.
3 servers are updated to CU11, last one is running CU10.
After the update to CU11 there are some piped commands I can't run on the servers that are updated to CU11, like this one:
Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients mail@mail.com

The error I get is this:

The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Exchangerservername:PSObject) [Get-MessageTrackingLog], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Get-MessageTrackingLog
+ PSComputerName        : xxxxxx
```

I have tried to write the command not copy.
Also tried to Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted.
Powershell version is the same on all servers.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way around this is to use a foreach:

```
get-transportservice | foreach {get-messagetrackinglog -resultsize unlimited `
 -start 05/21/2016 -recipient user@email.com}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your issue but there are known Exchange Management Shell issues with CU11. https://jaapwesselius.com/2016/01/19/exchange-2013-cumulative-update-11-install-it-or-not/ Here is a link.